# Matrix and scalar multiplication

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

Say we have the following variables:

- **A**, a matrix that is nxn in size containing complex numbers
- **B**, a matrix that is also nxn in size containing complex numbers
- x, a scalar

If you multiply, does it matter whether you multiply in either of the following orders:

- (**AB**)x
- (**A**x)**B**

if:

- x is a real number
- x is a complex number

Comment: Scalar multiplication is commutative, so no, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @DougM I knew it was commutative, but I didn't know whether it was associative with matrices and whether it plays a role that $x$ is in $\mathbb{C}$ and **A** and **B** are in $\mathbb{C^{n \cdot n}}$

Comment: @M.Vinay Thanks for pointing that out. I indeed know that in a lot of cases the brackets are only needed when multiple characters need to be `\somefunctionhere`'d.  I just do it out of force of habit :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs down to the [axiom of commutativity of multiplication in fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29#Definition_and_illustration) (a scalar is element of a field) 
$$
\forall a, b \in F: a b = b a
$$
and the commutative property of scalar multiplication: 
$$
x A 
= x(a_1, \dotsc, a_n) 
= (x a_1, \dots, x a_n) 
= (a_1 x, \dots, a_n x)
= (a_1, \dotsc, a_n) x
= A x
$$
where $x \in F$ and $A$ is a matrix over $F$. For matrix multiplication we have
$$
x \sum_j a_{ij} b_{jk}
= \sum_j (x a_{ij}) b_{jk}
= \sum_j a_{ij} (x b_{jk})
= \left(\sum_j a_{ij} b_{jk} \right) x
$$
or
$$
x(AB) = (xA)B = A(xB) = (AB)x
$$

Comment: Ok, that is a very sound explanation for real numbers. I verified that it is also true for complex numbers: a+ib = (a b, -b a) -> (a+ib)(c+id) = (a b, -b a)(c d, -d c) = (ac-bd ad+bc, -(ad+bc) ac-bd) = ac-bd + i(ad+bc). (c+id)(a+ib) = (c d, -d c)(a b, -b a) = (ca-db cb+da, -(cb+da) ca-db) = (ac-bd ad+bc, -(ad+bc) ac-bd) = ac-bd + i(ad+bc) QED

Comment: I also overlooked that you mentioned $∀a,b∈F:ab=ba$, Also, I forgot the formatting for the matrices, can you fix that? I don't have the right to edit after 5 min.

Comment: Complex numbers form a field, so they have commutative multiplication and more.

Answer (score 6):

$x(AB)=(xA)B=A(xB)=A(Bx)=(AB)x=(Ax)B$
When matrices are being multiplied by a scalar element, the order in which multiplication takes place can be disregarded

Answer (score 0):

Scalar multiplication actually is short hand for multiplication by a diagonal matrix full of the scalar. In other words:

$$sA = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}s&0&0\\0&\ddots&0\\0&0&s\end{array}\right]A$$

You can convince yourself that this will be the same when multiplying from the left as from the right.